# Regular expression for a polish phone number

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a **regular expression** to find polish phone numbers in a long string. There might be `+48`, `0048`, `48` (in brackets on not) followed by 9 digits with spaces in between.

The first idea was:

```
(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}
```

This captures things like `+48 123 456 789` and `123456789` but will also find 2 phone numbers in `1234567899876543211` - this is not acceptable. So I added word boundaries:

```
\b(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}\b
```

But this regex, in a string such as `(+48) 123 456 789` will only capture `48) 123 456 789`. Why is the beginning omitted?

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/irmjnT/5) with examples of what should match/shouldn't match)

Comment: Are the spaces always in groups of three?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm OK with some false negatives, so yeah, we can make this assumption.

Comment: That is because of a word boundary, move it to the digits. Before the non-word chars, add `\B`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't quite understand. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Please provide more sample input, with indication of "should be matched" / "should not be matched".

Comment: @Yunnosch I added a link to regex101

Comment: It seems you may add `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` rather than word boundaries to restrict the context for the matches, use https://regex101.com/r/irmjnT/4.

Comment: So everything in your linke before "Things not to capture:" should be captured?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, exactly. Wiktor's answer is exactly what I was looking for  :)

Comment: @Yunnosch sure, I was just waiting for those obligatory 2 minutes to pass  ;)

Comment: Ah. I did not know about those two minutes. I learned something thanks to you. And will probably keep that comment back in the future. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [`\b(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}\b` regex](https://regex101.com/r/2yweAv/1) did not match right the optional parts because the word boundary was obligatory while the optional patterns could be missing. E.g. the problem with `+48 123 456 789` string (where only `48 123 456 789` was matched) was the following: the initial `\b` required a word boundary, and there was no word boundary before `+`, thus it moved on and found `4` after `+` - that is where the word boundary is. Next, `(+48) 123 456 789` only yielded `48) 123 456 789` because the word boundary was only found between `+`  and `4` again.

Rather than playing with the word boundaries, you may directly tell the regex engine to only match the strings if they are not preceded nor followed with word chars.

Use

```
(?<!\w)(\(?(\+|00)?48\)?)?[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{3}(?!\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irmjnT/4)

The `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if there is a word char on the left of the match, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is a word char on the right of the match.

Comment: I still don't understand why my expression wasn't working, but your solution solves the problem very elegantly :)

Comment: Well, I added a small explanation why the last regex shared in the OP did not work. The explanation why adding word boundaries before optional patterns does not work is harder:  the point is that word boundaries are obligatory, while the pattern is not. I can only make word boundaries work with a conditional - see [this regex variation](https://regex101.com/r/XtQlY1/1) where `(...)` matching is a bit better (it won't match if there is one `(` or one `)`).

Comment: @Sonic Lookaheads have been supported in JS regex for ages, you must have meant "lookbehind". There are a lot of workarounds for that anyway, you do not need the lookbehind here. Just replace `(?<!\w)` with `(^|\W)`.

Comment: @AndrzejDzirba The question is related to Python, the regex is meant to be used with Python `re`. In JS, you need to use an alternation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212874/matching-whole-words-that-start-or-end-with-special-characters/52213075#52213075).