# Matching whole words that start or end with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in javascript that matches whole words that start or end with special characters?

It was supposed to be easy, but for some reason `\b` after `?` doesn't behave as I expected:

```
> /FOO\?/.exec('FOO? ')
[ 'FOO?', index: 0, input: 'FOO? ', groups: undefined ]
> /FOO\?\b/.exec('FOO? ')
null
```

What I need, for instance if my word is "FOO?" (including the question mark), I want to match:

"FOO? is cool", "do you think that FOO??"

but not: "FOO is cool", "FOO?is cool", "aaFOO?is cool"

It should also work for words that start with "?". For instance, if my word if "?FOO", I want to match:

"?FOO is cool", "I love ?FOO"

but not: "FOO is cool", "FOO?is cool", "aaFOO?is cool"

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Use `/FOO\?(?!\w)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the problem with your suggestion is that it matches `aaFOO?` which is not desired

Comment: So, add a word boundary before, use `/\bFOO\?(?!\w)/` or `/(?:^|\W)FOO\?(?!\w)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works. But it doesn't work if my word starts with `?` e.g. `?FOO`

Comment: [It works wonderfully](https://regex101.com/r/FjJV1N/1) as it matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `\b\?FOO\?(?!\w)/.exec('?FOO?')` is null, while it should match

Comment: Use `/(?:^|\W)\?FOO\?(?!\w)/` or `/(?<!\w)\?FOO\?(?!\w)/` with ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environments. I think you should provide a real life example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. It works. What is the meaning of `(?:^|W)`?

Comment: Start of string or `W`. I used `(?:^|\W)` though: start of string or any non-word char (not a letter, digit and `_`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you replacing or extracting these occurrences?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am extracting the occurences

Comment: So, did my solution finally work for you?

Comment: yes @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\b` word boundary construct is ambiguous. You need to use unambiguous constructs that will make sure there are non-word chars or start/end of string to the left/right of the word matched.

You may use

```
/(?:^|\W)\?FOO\?(?!\w)/g
```

Here, `(?:^|\W)` is a non-capturing group that matches either the start of a string or any non-word char, a char other than an ASCII letter, digit and `_`. `(?!\w)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is a word char.

Or, with ECMAScript 2018 compatible JS environments,

```
/(?<!\w)\?FOO\?(?!\w)/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qysg1r/1).

The `(?<!\w)` is a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the current location.

In code, you may use it directly with `String#match` to extract all occurrences, like `s.match(/(?<!\w)\?FOO\?(?!\w)/g)`.

The first expression needs a capturing group around the word you need to extract:

```js
var strs = ["?FOO is cool", "I love ?FOO", "FOO is cool", "FOO?is cool", "aaFOO?is cool"];
var rx = /(?:^|\W)(\?FOO)(?!\w)/g;
for (var s of strs) {
  var res = [], m;
  while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
  }
  console.log(s, "=>", res);
}
```