# Regexp - match specific word allowing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna make a regular expression to find specific word allowing special characters(`\W`). For example, if the word is `replace` then:

- `replace` matched.
- `replace(`, `$replace`,  `replace`, `replace`  matched because of allowing special characters.
- `areplace`, `replacea` not matched because of `a`.

It seems like I have to use `(?=)` operator, but I have no idea about how to use it.

Comment: @41686d6564 I mean `\W`

Comment: You're right. My bad. Do you want to include the "special character" in the match, or not?

Comment: `/[\W]*(replace)+[\W]*/`

Comment: hmm It doesn't matter

Comment: Then, you may use negative Lookarounds `(?<!\w)replace(?!\w)`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7kuyR/1).

Comment: **Duplicate of [Matching whole words that start or end with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212874/matching-whole-words-that-start-or-end-with-special-characters) and [How can I match a whole word in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232934/how-can-i-match-a-whole-word-in-javascript)**

Comment: Sorry, it is not an exact dupe of the other linked posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with word breaks and allowing any non-word, non-whitespace on either side:

```
[^\w\s]*\breplace\b[^\w\s]*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v7194V/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[^\w\s]0`: Match optional 0+ non-word and non-whitespace character
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `replace`: match text `replace`
- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[^\w\s]?`: Match optional 0+ non-word and non-whitespace character

Comment: Oops! bad copy/paste. Thanks, fixed

Comment: Yeah, it happens to the best of us :)